# jenkins integration xcode - shell command

Tags: ios, xcode, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have integrated my xcode project with jenkin.I have got xcode build succeeded, creating ipa but at the end "Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure" & Could not connect to SMTP host to send mail. Finished: FAILURE.

My Shell script is, xcodebuild -target EmailTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator | ./ocunit2junit.rb SMTP details copied from Mac Mail--> Preferences to Jenkins Configuration.

Kindly help me to clear this issue.

Comment: are you able to use mailx to send emails through your smtp host? that will help us figure out if you have a connection problem or some other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your command: 
`xcodebuild -target EmailTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator | ./ocunit2junit.rb` from a shell in Terminal. If it has the same error when you run outside Jenkins you can stop worring about Jenkins. If it dose work, try to figure out how the 2 environments differ.

Also try connecting to the smtp server manually, from the same machine that you are running the test on. First look up the smpt server using `nslookup` then connect with `telnet` to tcp port 25. Here are details for checking the mail connection: https://www.port25.com/how-to-check-an-smtp-connection-with-a-manual-telnet-session-2/

Answer (score 1):

Seems more like Jenkins configuration issue.
Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and apply the changes as show in screenshot.[image]